# Organization acronym in citation and bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, citing, acronyms

In my document, there is a reference to an organization that needs to be shown as `Office International des Epizooties (OIE), 2012...`. But in in-text citation, I need it to show as `OIE, 2012`.

To achieve this, I used `author={{Office International des Epizooties (OIE)}}` in bib, but that outputs the whole name in in-text citation (`Office International des Epizooties (OIE), 2012`). I have tried `author={{Office International des Epizooties}}, shortauthor={{OIE}}`, but it does not work, probably because I am using `natbib` package.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you didn't provide much information, I can only give you a hint how it might work under natbib: You can create an alias for citing with `\defcitealias{yourTag}{OIE, 2012}` and then quote it in the text with `\citetalias{yourTag}` (printed without brackets) or `\citepalias{yourTag}` (printed with brackets). Then the alias is printed instead of the author. *yourTag is the reference name you gave the entry in your bib-file.

Here is an MWE, to show you how it could work:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{oie,
    author={{Office International des Epizooties (OIE)}},
    title = {The title of the book},
    year = {2020}
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage{natbib}
\defcitealias{oie}{OIE, 2012}

\begin{document}
\section*{Section with citations}
\verb|\cite{oie}|: \cite{oie}\\
\verb|\citetalias{oie}|: \citetalias{oie}\\
\verb|\citepalias{oie}|: \citepalias{oie}

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. Exactly what I needed.